# codeigniter show json format well on my pc, but in other pc doesn´t

Tags: json, codeigniter

i have a problem..... i´m try to implement a rest_client with codeigniter3.1.7, i have implanted the code in the final server, then i have tested the link on my desktop (firefox, windows7), and i see it very well in [json format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z653N.png) (like this image),
but if i try to see it in another pc, it only show me the brute json response, [brute json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uv0QN.png).
At this time i´m printing the json in the controller, this is the code

```
$config = array('server'        => 'http://api.mercadopublico.cl/',
                //'api_key'         => 'Setec_Astronomy'
                //'api_name'        => 'X-API-KEY'
                //'http_user'       => 'username',
                //'http_pass'       => 'password',
                //'http_auth'       => 'basic',
                //'ssl_verify_peer' => TRUE,
                //'ssl_cainfo'      => '/certs/cert.pem'
                );

    // Run some setup
    $this->rest->initialize($config);
    $test = $this->rest->get('servicios/v1/Publico/Empresas/BuscarProveedor?rutempresaproveedor=70.017.820-k&ticket=F8537A18-6766-4DEF-9E59-426B4FEE2844');

    $this->output->set_header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8')
        ->set_output(json_encode(array($test)));
```

Can somebody help me?

pd: sorry for my english :)

Comment: Hola... What you're seeing is exactly the same correctly-formed json structure. The only difference is that on your computer it's being presented on screen after **local** parsing. If that doesn't happen on other computers it's very likely due to not having the same (local) software or configuration. There's nothing wrong with your code and the json being returned by Chilecompra is usable.

Comment: ok, thank you very much, but i dont know what type of configuration it is needed in the other conputers, php version maybe?

Comment: No. This doesn't have anything to do with the server your code is running in... It's what you're doing **locally** (read: client  side) with the json being returned by the server

Comment: The fact that your computer displays the json in parsed form doesn't mean that the server is returning anything other than the raw (not brute :) )  json. Are you using the same browser on other computers? Does your computer have any browser extensions that the others don't? Think about local differences and you'll find the answer. But regardless, your code is running fine, don't let this delay your development

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, the other computers have firefox too, and one of them it is a debian (firefox on debian)